# How to access WSGIRequest multiple times?

Tags: django, rest, django-rest-framework, httprequest

I have an APIView that calls another APIView for check purpose, But after hours of searching I know now that it's not easy to access `HttpRequest` after turn into stream object and will cause the below error:

> django.http.request.RawPostDataException: You cannot access body after
> reading from request's data stream

some are suggest to use `request.data` not `request.body` but I can't do it in such case:

**B.views.py**

```py
from rest_framework import views
from rest_framework.response import Response

from A.views import A

class B(views.APIView):

   def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

       http_response = A.as_view()(request._request)

       # So far so good, but if I want to access request.data after calling A.as_view() will raise 
       # the exception. 

       return Response(http_response.data)
```

How to deal with this issue?

**source**: [issue2774](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/issues/2774)

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple suggestions I found:

1- use `Middleware` to store the `request.body` to use it later in case of need.

2- use a custom parser class that store raw data as property in the `request` object before converting it into `stream` object.

Both of them I found is a little bit complicated, so I changed the way of calling another `APIView` from certain DRF `View`, as shown:

```py
from rest_framework import views, status
from rest_framework.response import Response

from A.views import A
from C.views import C

class B(views.APIView):

   def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

       # Initialize a new instance of class view 'A'  
       a_view = A()

       # Calling HTTP 'POST' method with DRF request object.
       a_http_response = a_view.post(request)

       if a_http_response.status_code == status.status.HTTP_200_OK:

          # Initialize a new instance of class view 'C'  
          c_view = C()

          # Another calling HTTP 'POST' method with DRF request object.
          c_http_response = c_view.post(request)

          return(c_http_response.data)
       
       else:
          return Response(a_http_response.data)
```